# Python- UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment - Regular Expressions/if else

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to make my program function so that each regex .findAll() method is correctly feeding into the HTML parser as seen in the code snippet below. The issue is that I am getting

> UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment

for headingList and imageList, depending on how I change my code. I think this is because of the if statements not continuing past the first if block as it is true. I tried using `if heading and image and description and storyLink and date:` and creating all of the variables inside the one for loop but when I run the program nothing happens what so ever. I think it is the structure of my code, or it may even be the regular expression for the image variable that may be causing the issue, but I don't think so. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

EDIT: [HTML snippet being used to parse from regex](http://prntscr.com/gwitcv)

```
def extractNews():
    selection = listbox.curselection()

    if selection == (0,):
        # Read the webpage:
        response = urlopen("file:///E:/University/IFB104/InternetArchive/Archives/Sun,%20October%201st,%202017.html")
        html = response.read()
        #regex
        heading = findall((r'<h2 class="post-title"><a href="(.*?)".*?>(.*?)</a></h2>'), str(html))
        image = findall((r'<span data-omni-sm-delegate="(.*)">(\n|\r)\s+<a href="(.*)></a>(\n|\r)\s+</span>'), str(html))  #<span data-omni-sm-delegate="(.*)">(\n|\r)\s+<a href="(.*)></a>(\n|\r)\s+</span>
        description = findall((r'<h2 class="post-title"><a href="(.*?)".*?>(.*?)</a></h2>'), str(html))
        storyLink = findall((r'<h2 class="post-title"><a href="(.*?)".*?>(.*?)</a></h2>'), str(html))
        date = findall((r'<h2 class="post-title"><a href="(.*?)".*?>(.*?)</a></h2>'), str(html))

        if heading:
            headingList = []
            for link, title in heading:
                headingVariable = "%s" % (title)
                headingList.append(headingVariable)

        if image:
            imageList = []
            for link, title in image:
                imageVariable = "%s" % (title)
                imageList.append(imageVariable)

        if description:
            descriptionList = []
            for link, title in description:
                descriptionVariable = "%s" % (title)
                descriptionList.append(descriptionVariable)

        if storyLink:
            storyLinkList = []
            for link, title in storyLink:
                storyLinkVariable = "%s" % (title)
                storyLinkList.append(storyLinkVariable)

        if date:
            dateList = []
            for link, title in date:
                dateVariable = "%s" % (title)
                dateList.append(dateVariable)




        html_str = ('<!DOCTYPE html>\n'
        '<html>\n'
        '<head>\n'
        '<title>TechCrunch Archive - Sun, October 1st, 2017</title>\n'
        '</head>\n'
        '<body>\n'
        '<h1>' + headingList[0] + '</h1>\n'
        '<a href="'+ imageList[0]+'></a>\n'
        '<p>description goes here</p>\n'
        '<p>full story link goes here</p>\n'
        '<p>date goes here</p>\n'
        '<br><br>\n'
        '<h1>' + headingList[1] + '</h1>\n'
        'image goes here\n'
        '<p>description goes here</p>\n'
        '<p>full story link goes here</p>\n'
        '<p>date goes here</p>\n'
        '<br><br>\n'
        '<h1>' + headingList[2] + '</h1>\n'
        'image goes here\n'
        '<p>description goes here</p>\n'
        '<p>full story link goes here</p>\n'
        '<p>date goes here</p>\n'
        '<br><br>\n'
        '</body>\n'
        '</html>)')

        Html_file = open("ExtractedContent/Sun, October 1st, 2017 - Extracted.html", "w")
        Html_file.write(html_str)
        Html_file.close()
```

Comment: You checked that the values of `heading` and `image` are what you expect, right?

Comment: If I use the same regular expression in heading for image, the problem does not occur and imports fine. However when my attempted regex expression is used it returns the error. I thought this may be the case but I didn't think a wrong regular expression would cause the problem. I expected it to just import the wrong content. Do you know why this may be the case?

Comment: What values re you getting for `heading` and `image`, and do they differ from what you expected?

Comment: [this](http://prntscr.com/gwir3m) is what i'm expecting to see inside the <a></a> tags as shown in the HTML parser. If I use the regex as shown in that link, I get the unboundLocalError. I cannot check what the output is due to this error.

Comment: WHAT VALUES ARE YOU GETTING FOR `header` AND `image`?  The error happens AFTER these get assigned.

Comment: header returns `[('https://web.archive.org/web/20171001000310/https://techcrunch.com/2017/09/30/where-human-intelligence-outperforms-ai/', 'Where human intelligence outperforms AI'),` for each heading, and image returns `[]`

Answer (score 1):

> I think this is because of the if statements not continuing past the
>   first if block as it is true.

That would be the case for `if / elif`.
Your conditions are not true, so lists are not created, probably (hard to tell without having `html`) because `findall` did not find anything and returned an empty list which is `False`.

> I tried using `if heading and image and description and storyLink and date:` 
>   and creating all of the variables inside the one for loop but
>   when I run the program nothing happens what so ever.

Nothing happens because not all conditions are `True`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `image` is `[]`, `if image` fails, and `imageList` is never assigned to.

So check the regex used for `image`.  Better yet, use a proper parser (for example, HTMLParser).

Comment: I don't understand what has gone wrong as [these](http://prntscr.com/gwixel) [two](https://prnt.sc/gwitcv) snippets make sense don't they? The regex doesn't seem wrong to me..?

Comment: Python disagrees, and its opinion counts.

Comment: Can you spot any problems? I'm pretty new to regular expressions so i'm finding it hard.

Comment: Well I have been for hours now and only now resulted to this post :/ It seems like it's working [fine](http://prntscr.com/gwj6pr) until I put it into python.

Comment: And you are looking for help in parsing a file whose content you have only provided an picture of.

Comment: does [this](https://pastebin.com/kCS0uXSr) help? otherwise [here](https://pastebin.com/MgmvHiJ3) is the full .html

Comment: Use a proper HTML parser.

Comment: yes I know about beautiful soup and all of these beneficial things on the internet that would make my life easier. too bad i'm restricted from using any external libraries and that's why i'm trying to get help? thanks for your help i guess.